# Timeseries Analysis: Group data by month so I can look at it per month

Tags: python, pandas, date, time, time-series

I was wondering how I could group data by month so I can look at the data on a per month basis. How would i do that?

for example, assign january for all data recorded in january in their own dataframe for analysis, etc.

here is my current dataframe:

```
   WC_Humidity[%]  WC_Htgsetp[C]  WC_Clgsetp[C]       Date   Time  
0       55.553640             18             26 2005-01-01  00:10  
1       54.204342             18             26 2005-01-01  00:20  
2       51.896272             18             26 2005-01-01  00:30  
3       49.007770             18             26 2005-01-01  00:40  
4       45.825810             18             26 2005-01-01  00:50
```

help is much appreciated.

Comment: do you want `groupby` month or `sort` by month.

Comment: `dayfirst = True` doesn't format as `DD-MM-YYYY` but it only inform pandas how to parse string with date - as `DD-MM-YYYY` or as `MM-DD-YYYY`

Comment: Groupby month, so I could select only data recorded in january for example

Comment: if you want `groupby` then simply get `2005-01` from strings `2005-01-01` - (ie. `"2005-01-01"[:7]` gives `"2005-01"`) and create new column with `2005-01` and use this column in `groupby()`

Comment: if you have already objects `datetime` then use `.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')` to create strings like `2005-01` and then use this value to group it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```html
df1['Date'].to_numpy().astype('datetime64[M]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your column with following code.

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
```

And you can refer official document for why dayfirst is not working.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

If the column is in this format 2021-01-29, 30-12-2024 then  before the above line should take care of it and parse it accordingly.

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
```

Now you can use this code to convert the date column to the way you wanted.

```
df1['Date'] = df['Date1'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

This should get you what you want.

Comment: okay this is good, but how do I assign a variable for a months worth of data. for example, if I use the following:

Comment: January = any data that has the date XX/01/2005

Comment: for my data analysis, so i can compare months

Comment: So you have 1 column and that column has multiple date formats? It's not in this format 2021/01/01?

Answer (score 0):

If you have strings like `2005-01-01` then you can get

```
df['year-month'] = df['Date'].str[:7]
```

and later you can use

```
df.groupby('year-month')
```

---

Minimal working code.

I changed dates to have different months in data.

I use `io` only to simulate file in memory.

```
text = '''WC_Humidity[%],WC_Htgsetp[C],WC_Clgsetp[C],Date,Time
55.553640,18,26,2005-01-01,00:10
54.204342,18,26,2005-01-01,00:20
51.896272,18,26,2005-02-01,00:30
49.007770,18,26,2005-02-01,00:40
45.825810,18,26,2005-03-01,00:50
'''

import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text))

df['year-month'] = df['Date'].str[:7]

print(df)

for value, group in df.groupby('year-month'):
    print()
    print('---', value, '---')
    print(group)
    print()
    print('average WC_Humidity[%]:', group['WC_Humidity[%]'].mean())
```

Result:

```
   WC_Humidity[%]  WC_Htgsetp[C]  WC_Clgsetp[C]       Date   Time year-month
0       55.553640             18             26 2005-01-01  00:10    2005-01
1       54.204342             18             26 2005-01-01  00:20    2005-01
2       51.896272             18             26 2005-02-01  00:30    2005-02
3       49.007770             18             26 2005-02-01  00:40    2005-02
4       45.825810             18             26 2005-03-01  00:50    2005-03

--- 2005-01 ---
   WC_Humidity[%]  WC_Htgsetp[C]  WC_Clgsetp[C]       Date   Time year-month
0       55.553640             18             26 2005-01-01  00:10    2005-01
1       54.204342             18             26 2005-01-01  00:20    2005-01

average WC_Humidity[%]: 54.878991

--- 2005-02 ---
   WC_Humidity[%]  WC_Htgsetp[C]  WC_Clgsetp[C]       Date   Time year-month
2       51.896272             18             26 2005-02-01  00:30    2005-02
3       49.007770             18             26 2005-02-01  00:40    2005-02

average WC_Humidity[%]: 50.452021

--- 2005-03 ---
   WC_Humidity[%]  WC_Htgsetp[C]  WC_Clgsetp[C]       Date   Time year-month
4        45.82581             18             26 2005-03-01  00:50    2005-03

average WC_Humidity[%]: 45.82581
```

---

If you have objects `datetime` then you can do

```
df['year-month'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

and rest is the same

```
text = '''WC_Humidity[%],WC_Htgsetp[C],WC_Clgsetp[C],Date,Time
55.553640,18,26,2005-01-01,00:10
54.204342,18,26,2005-01-01,00:20
51.896272,18,26,2005-02-01,00:30
49.007770,18,26,2005-02-01,00:40
45.825810,18,26,2005-03-01,00:50
'''

import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text))

# create datetime objects
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

df['year-month'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

print(df)

for value, group in df.groupby('year-month'):
    print()
    print('---', value, '---')
    print(group)
    print()
    print('average WC_Humidity[%]:', group['WC_Humidity[%]'].mean())
```